# Finding angle of intersecting lines

Tags: geometry

[image][image]![

$\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ACE$ are equilateral triangles. Can it be proved that $\triangle ADC$ and $\triangle ABE$ are congruent. Or if given they are congruent what is the value of $\angle BOD$?

Another similar problem with square replacing the equilateral triangles have been added.Where $\angle BOE=?$

][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnkVX.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Observe that you can rotate $\triangle ADC$ around point $A$ to get $\triangle ABE$. The rest follows from properties of rotation. The very same technique can be applied to the problem with squares.

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: i have doen it like this: